# Aspect ratio for Android in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

If anyone can help me with this issue that i am having after creating a gaming app in unity.

Actually everything went well, except the aspect ratio of the mobile.

I had chosen the aspect ratio to to be 720x1280 and now it runs on that screen size only. If I try to run it on different screen size, it just does not, it gets stretched and nothing displays as developed. I have been searching for this for weeks. I also tried to change the aspect ratio of the game in unity editor only but whole things gets disrupt, so I can't undo the coding also, it'll take a lot of time again.

Please if anyone can help me, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [Designing UI for Multiple Resolutions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html). But if you have already adjusted the canvas and all its objects for different resolutions,  [Controlling Aspect Ratio in Unity](http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.com/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html)  might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with using canvas elements, they all have RectTransform components by default(instead of Transform). All game object with RectTransform has it's anchor and pivot and only thing you have to do is construct them properly.

You can watch this tutorial(or find other videos too on same topic) and it will help you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ad-Q9hYCnCg

Answer (score 0):

Select **Canvas** , and in the inspector go to **Canvas Scaler** -> **UI Scale Mode** and select **Scale With Screen Size**

[image]